# Slick Carousel - conflicting filter functions breaking each other (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I have a model bar for a website using the slick carousel, there are multiple filters that on desktop are being controlled by an  and on tablet/mobile being controlled by a  drop down. They work independently of each other but if I choose one filter on desktop and then shrink the window down and choose a different filter slider breaks or because unresponsive.

I have two seperate functions for each filter selector and ideally it would be best if they could be combined but my javascript skills just are not that good, I have fiddled around with this for a little too long now and have officially thrown in the towel. Any help would be greatly appreciated and please don't judge my code too harshly

HTML

```
<!--=======Vehicle Scroller Section=======-->
<div class="scroller-container">
  <div class="wrapper row vehicle-type-selector">
  <div class="show-for-medium-up">
        <ul class="columns column-1 large-12 medium-12 small-12">
            <span id="all-vehicles" class="active"><li>All Vehicles</li></span>
            <span id="car"><li>Cars</li></span>
            <span id="truck"><li>Minivans &amp; Trucks</li></span>
            <span id="suv"><li>Crossovers &amp; SUVs</li></span>
            <span id="hybrid"><li>Hybrids &amp; EVs</li></span>
        </ul>
  </div>

  <select class="columns column-2 large-12 medium-12 small-12 show-for-small-only">
    <option class="all-vehicles">All Vehicles</option>
    <option class="car">Cars</option>
    <option class="truck">Minivans &amp; Trucks</option>
    <option class="suv">Crossovers &amp; SUVs</option>
    <option class="hybrid">Hybrids &amp; EVs</option>
  </select>
    </div>

  <div class="vehicle-scroller">
    <div class="wrapper row">
        <div class="veh-pagenation">
            <span id="slickPrev" class="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i></span>
            <span id="slickNext" class="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span>
        </div>


        <div class="model-container">
          <div class="all-vehicles car">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-1"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Yaris</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$14,845</span> msrp | <span class="bold">30/37</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles car">
          <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-2"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2016 <span class="bold">Corolla</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$17,230</span> msrp | <span class="bold">28/37</span> est. mpg</p>
            <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles car">
            <span class="veh-container ">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-3"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2016 <span class="bold">Camry</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$23,070</span> msrp | <span class="bold">25/35</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles car">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-4"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Avalon</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$32,285</span> msrp | <span class="bold">21/31</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles truck">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-5"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Sienna</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$28,700</span> msrp | <span class="bold">18/25</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles truck">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-6"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Tacoma</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$20,965</span> msrp | <span class="bold">21/25</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles truck">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-7"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2016 <span class="bold">Tundra</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$28,640</span> msrp | <span class="bold">15/19</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles suv">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-8"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Rav-4</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$23,680</span> msrp | <span class="bold">24/31</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles suv">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-9"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Venza</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$29,065</span> msrp | <span class="bold">20/26</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles suv">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-10"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Highlander</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$29,765</span> msrp | <span class="bold">20/25</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles suv">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-11"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2016 <span class="bold">4Runner</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$33,510</span> msrp | <span class="bold">17/22</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles suv">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-12"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2016 <span class="bold">Sequoia</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$44,965</span> msrp | <span class="bold">13/17</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles suv">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-13"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Land Cruiser</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$80,155</span> msrp | <span class="bold">13/18</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles hybrid">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-14"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2016 <span class="bold">Camry Hybrid</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$26,790</span> msrp | <span class="bold">43/39</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles hybrid">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-15"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Avalon Hybrid</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$36,470</span> msrp | <span class="bold">40/39</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles hybrid">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-16"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Highlander Hybrid</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$47,850</span> msrp | <span class="bold">27/28</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles hybrid">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-17"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Prius</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$24,200</span> msrp | <span class="bold">51/48</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles hybrid">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-18"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Prius C</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$19,540</span> msrp | <span class="bold">53/46</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>

          <div class="all-vehicles hybrid">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-19"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2015 <span class="bold">Prius Plug-In Hybrid</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$29,990</span> msrp | EPA est. <span class="bold">95 Ev Mode/50 hybrid mode</span></p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="all-vehicles hybrid">
            <span class="veh-container">
                <div class="veh-thumb model-20"></div>
                <p class="model-name">2016 <span class="bold">Prius V</span></p>
                <p class="mpg"><span class="bold">$26,675</span> msrp | <span class="bold">44/40</span> est. mpg</p>
                <a href="#" class="button">View Details <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    //vehicle scroller
  $('.model-container').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    prevArrow: $('.veh-pagenation #slickPrev'),
    nextArrow: $('.veh-pagenation #slickNext'),
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1020,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          arrows: false,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          arrows: false,
        }
      }
    ]
  });

var filtered = false;


  $(".vehicle-type-selector select").change(function() {
    if ($(".vehicle-type-selector span.active").length) {
      $(".vehicle-type-selector span.active").removeClass("active");
      var filtered = true;
    } else {
      var filtered = false;
    }

    var filtername = $("option:selected").attr('class');

    if (filtered === false) {
      $('.model-container').slick('slickUnfilter');
      $('.model-container').slick('slickFilter', '.' + filtername);
    } else {
      $('.model-container').slick('slickUnfilter');
      $('.model-container').slick('slickFilter', '.' + filtername);
      $('.model-container').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
      filtered = false;
    }

    if ($(".vehicle-type-selector span.active").length) {
      $(".vehicle-type-selector span.active").removeClass("active");
    }

    if ($(".vehicle-type-selector option:selected").length) {
      $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    }

    $('.vehicle-type-selector select').find('option.' + filtername).attr('selected','selected');
    $(".vehicle-type-selector span#" + filtername).toggleClass("active");

    });

  $(".vehicle-type-selector span").on('click', function(){
    if ($(".vehicle-type-selector option:selected").length) {
      $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
      var filtered = true;
    } else {
      var filtered = false;
    }


   var filtername = $(this).attr('id');

  if (filtered === false) {
    $('.model-container').slick('slickUnfilter');
    $('.model-container').slick('slickFilter', '.' + filtername);
  } else {
    $('.model-container').slick('slickUnfilter');
    $('.model-container').slick('slickFilter', '.' + filtername);
    $('.model-container').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
    filtered = false;
  }

  if ($(".vehicle-type-selector span.active").length) {
    $(".vehicle-type-selector span.active").removeClass("active");
  }

  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $('.vehicle-type-selector select').find('option.' + filtername).attr('selected','selected');


  if($(".model-container .slick-track").children().length < 5) {
    $(".veh-pagenation").hide();
  } else {
    $(".veh-pagenation").show();
  }
  console.log("arrows");

});
```

here a url to the "working" model http://schottman-toyotadesign.schottmandesign.com